# Como varrer a matriz usando apenas um for?

Tags: java, array, matriz, otimização

As circunstâncias estão no código que funciona:

```
    String[][] compras = new String[][] { { "item 1", "1.70" }, { "item 2", "39.90" }, { "item 3", "9.90" }, { "item 4", "4.90" }, { "item 5", "7.90" } };
            
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < compras.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < compras[i].length; j++) {

            if (j == 1) {
                soma = (int) (soma + Double.parseDouble(compras[i][j]));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total das compras: R$ " + soma);
}
```

Comment: Importante sempre que postar uma pergunta, explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

De fato o laço interno não faz sentido, ele percorre uma dimensão mas só quer um elemento, então use esse elemento em vez de percorrer todos eles. Na prática só precisa do índice 1 e não percorrer tudo. So jeito que está o `j` é variante, mas o `if` faz ele só ser útil como constante.

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[][] compras = new String[][] {
                { "item 1", "1.70" }, { "item 2", "39.90" }, { "item 3", "9.90" }, { "item 4", "4.90" },
                { "item 5", "7.90" } };
        int soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < compras.length; i++) soma = (int)(soma + Double.parseDouble(compras[i][1]));
        System.out.println("Total das compras: R$ " + soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Opvab3). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/miqbtngw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/LiteralIndex.java).

Outro detalhe importante é que parece estar usando [valores monetários que não podem ser representados com o tipo `Double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: Muito obrigada!! me ajudou muito!! sucesso!

Comment: @Mariana veja no [tour] que você pode a aceitar a resposta se ela resolveu seu problema.